# Booting from another partition via bash

Tags: partition, startup, bash

I want to create a little bash script that restart my mac and boots from another partition. Of course I could do that with changing the startup partition, but that would cause that it would always boot from it. It should only do that if the script will be executed. 
Is that possible? And if so, how?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What operating system is running on the other partition?

Comment: Lookup the `bless` command